# daily orders on average that are placed on the region

Tags: oracle

I have to create one query to fetch the % of orders that go for region, for the last 5 days.
- Total # of daily orders on average that are placed on the region store (ProcessingStatus = Processed)

i created below query...please help me match above conditions...

```
SELECT trunc(order_date) as Order_Date, COUNT(web_order_number) AS NoOfOrders, 
           SUM(order_total) AS daily_total, scr.STORE_CONFIGURATION_ID, scr.COUNTRY
FROM purchase_order po 
INNER JOIN STORE_CONFIG_REFERENCE scr 
ON po.STORE_CONFIGURATION_ID = scr.STORE_CONFIGURATION_ID 
WHERE po.PROCESSING_STATUS = 'processed' and po.order_date >= trunc(sysdate - 4) 
GROUP BY trunc(order_date) ORDER BY order_date ASC;
```

getting error now: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.`

and How to calculate % of orders

Comment: you want to add `scr.STORE_CONFIGURATION_ID, scr.COUNTRY` in group by or else remove it from select according to your business requirements

Comment: yaa its working...but i have to display the Region name along with that.

Comment: Can you tell me this one is right...Please..

Comment: Region name in select statement ?

Comment: SELECT trunc(order_date) as Order_Date, COUNT(web_order_number)/5 AS NoOfOrders, SUM(order_total) AS daily_total
FROM purchase_order WHERE PROCESSING_STATUS = 'processed' and order_date >= trunc(sysdate - 4) and STORE_CONFIGURATION_ID in 
(123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130) GROUP BY trunc(order_date) ORDER BY order_date ASC;

Comment: Seems correct, this is not right place to ask. visit to chat.stackoverflow.com